# Error using imcontrast tool in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a problem with imcontrast tool.
I read 2D dicom image, then convert it to 16bits(im2uint16) and perform filtration and windowing using imcontrast.
It shows me a warning message:

[image]

How Can I prevent then ?
How can I change data range in imtool ?

I would appreciate for any help please.

Comment: where does that 51156 comes from? It is a very strange number....

Comment: Could you post some code to reproduce your problem possibly using one of Matlabs built in images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [0,51156] is the range of the image data which change from image to image. [0, 65535] are the default color axis limits for uint16, which are outside the image data range, causing the re-adjust warning prompt. If you wish to silence the prompt you can manually set the color axis limits before calling imcontrast by:

```
caxis([double(min(min(Image))), double(max(max(Image)))]);
```

The conversion to double is to prevent a datatype mismatch. max() and min() return an uint16 value with uint16 data, which causes an another error down the line.